# Android web service-dataset

Tags: android, web-services

I general how to write a web method for the web service which is returning the value as "dataset" by consuming it from android.

Is this web-method right?

```
public class GetName
{
 public DataSet GetName(String str)
 {
    return str;
}
}
```

If not please let me now any idea or sample sources.I have googled it as per my knowledge but still searching for solution.

Thanks for your precious time!

Comment: The question you have posted its not fully understand at my side..

Comment: which plat form you are using .net or java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I considered you are developing web service in java.
No there is no data type as data set in java but if you want you can return response as array of String.It mean get response(table) in 2D array of string and return that response.